# Ruby importing local variables from Module

Tags: ruby, module, scope

```
module Mod
  var = 2 
end

class Person
  include Mod
  puts var
end
```

Simple question. Why can't i access a local variable imported from a module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a local variable. That's what they're there for. Local variables are local to the lexical scope they are defined in. That's why they are called local variables.

Answer (score 3):

When you are including a *module* inside another *module or class*, [Ruby’s default implementation is to add the *constants*, *methods*, and *module variables*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-append_features) of this module to mod(where you are including the module) if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its *ancestors*.

In your case `var` is a local variable of module `Mod`, so it can't be included inside the class `Person`, by the line `include Mod`.